# (ZyBooks Python) Nested loops: Print seats

Tags: python, while-loop, nested

Long story short, I'm taking Intro Python and this is the problem in question:

Given num_rows and num_cols, print a list of all seats in a theater. Rows are numbered, columns lettered, as in 1A or 3E. Print a space after each seat.

Sample output with inputs: 2 3
1A 1B 1C 2A 2B 2C

```
num_rows = int(input())
num_cols = int(input())

# Note 1: You will need to declare more variables
# Note 2: Place end=' ' at the end of your print statement to separate seats by spaces

'''Insert your solution here'''

print()
```

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[zybooks](/questions/tagged/zybooks)[nested](/questions/tagged/nested)[loop](/questions/tagged/loop)

Someone else had already posted the question and I tweaked the code from that post to get the following with soft-coded variables to run with user input and verified it works:

```
num_rows = int(input())
num_cols = int(input())

# Note 1: You will need to declare more variables
# Note 2: Place end=' ' at the end of your print statement to separate seats by spaces

row = 1
while row <= num_rows:
    col = 'A'
    while col < chr(ord('A') + num_cols):
        print('{}{}'.format(row, col), end=' ')
        col = chr(ord(col) + 1)
    row += 1
print()
```

My question is **WHAT** is going with the column/string in this example?  The rows are easy, it's a simple integer initialized with 1, easy to understand how it behaves and why '<=' is used for the outer while loop.  The columns, in other words the string-to-ASCII-to-string conversion kind of breaks my brain.  Can anyone break this down Barney style for me?  Specifically, why does only '<' work?

Answer (score 0):

The uppercase letters (A to Z) have consecutive ASCII values (65 to 90). For each row, the question requires printing out the first `num_cols` uppercase characters of the alphabet concatenated with the row number.

The consecutive range of integers starting from a number `n` of length `l` ends at `n + l - 1`. (You can try a few examples to convince yourself.)

`ord('A')` returns the Unicode code point of the character `'A'`, which is 65. After adding `num_cols` to it, we get the code point of the character right after the range of characters. (`<=` could be used if `1` was subtracted to get the actual endpoint of the range.) `chr` converts the code point to the actual character. `<` will be `True` until the `col` character reaches the character `chr(ord('A') + num_cols)`, which is one past the end of the range.

Along the same vein, `col = chr(ord(col) + 1)` advances `col` to the character with a code point that has a value one greater than the code point of the current `col` character. This is just like incrementing an index variable when iterating over a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
i =1
while i<= num_rows:
  i2='A'
  v=1
  while v <= num_cols:

    print('{}{}'.format(i,i2),end=' ')
    i2= chr(ord(i2)+1)
    v +=1
i+=1
```

print()

### There are inputs that names num_row and num_cols who both equal int(input()) so we can get any integer "ending point"